# Objective-C release for unnamed(temporary, non-lvalue) variables

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I trying to learn Objective-C memory management, and was wondering if I can write my code to work properly in both ARC and Non-ARC cases. So ended up with following code, where did not name any variable:

```
CFStringRef fileref_to_localpath(CFStringRef fileRefURL)
{
    // one liner to convert file URL(like file:///<path>) to machine specific path
    return (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSURL URLWithString:(__bridge NSString *)fileRefURL] path];
}
```

So, my question do I need to release something that I did not name in first place?

Comment: removed irrelevant part of code.

Answer (score -1):

1) First of all: Core Foundation objects are not "auto-countable", so you have to write CFRelease and CFRetain whenever you work with CF type whether it's ARC or MRC.

__bridge is not transferring ownership to/from ARC, it just "casts" object to desired type. Having this in mind, you should think of your code in two different ways: ARC and MRC.

In ARC - you should call CFRelease on CF objects when you finished with them, only if originally this object was obtained with CF and You are responsible for it. The main rule of object responsibility is: If you created an object or got it with functions with "Create" or "Copy" - then you are responsible for it.

In MRC - you should retain when you are planning to use temporary object in future, and release it later when you are done with it and/or use autorelease.

2) Second point:

```
CFStringRef url = (CFStringRef)@"file:///home/gautam/index.cpp";
```

has excessive allocations, use CFSTR(const char *) instead like:

```
CFStringRef url = CFSTR("file:///home/gautam/index.cpp");
```

According to Apple docs

> A value returned by CFSTR has the following semantics:
>
> Values returned from CFSTR are not released by CFString—they are
>   guaranteed to be valid until the program terminates.
>
> You can retain and release values returned from CFSTR in a balanced
>   fashion, like any other CFString, but you are not required to do so.

3) here:

```
return (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSURL URLWithString:(__bridge NSString *)fileRefURL] path];
```

Even new NSURL object is created, you are not responsible to release it in MRC because URLWithString: and path don't start with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”. (thanks @Willeke) This mean that they are already in autorelease pool.

See [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) for help. (Also was useful for me)

Correct me if I am wrong.

P.S. If you want to transfer object from CF to NS or from NS to CF 
for "forever", look at CFBridgingRelease and CFBridgingRetain

UPD: corrected post according to comments

Comment: So, I should write my code code like following(regardless of reference counting context):

```CFStringRef fileref_to_localpath(CFStringRef fileRefURL)
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSURL URLWithString:(__bridge NSString *)fileRefURL] path];
}
}```

Comment: No, this is wrong. 
You should call -[NSObject autorelease] method, not @autoreleasepool block.
I will not teach how to use it. Instead, there is a good manual page at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsautoreleasepool.

Comment: `+[NSURL URLWithString:]`and `-[NSURL path]` return autoreleased values.

Comment: @Willeke where did you find it? And why you think so? Is there any docs for it? I read official docs and there is nothing said about autoreleased objects.

Comment: I know because I'm used to MRC and all similar class methods return an autoreleased object. See [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1). `URLWithString:` and `path` don't start with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for explanation, I will edit my post.